# Find latitude/longitude of northernmost, southernmost, westernmost, and easternmost points in county

Tags: latitude-longitude, united-states, county

I need to find the latitudes of the northernmost and southernmost points, and the longitude of the easternmost and westernmost points, in two US counties (one in Oregon and one in California). What is the best way to get this information?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: county bounding box extents https://observablehq.com/@rdmurphy/u-s-county-bounding-boxes-by-state

Comment: @Pointdump I was trying to find a program that would work. Sorry if I misunderstood the site; are all questions supposed to be about a particular program?

Comment: Thank you @Mapperz! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] to better understand our purpose. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, so all Questions should always specify the software in use and what has been attempted.